# Sorting an array of integers using algorithm with complexity O(n)

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I red already that the best sort comparison algorithms have complexity O(nlog(n)). But I'm asked to sort an array of integers(in C) using a sorting algorithm of complexity O(n) given that *all the elements in the array are non-negative and less than a constant K*. But I have no idea how to use this information in the sorting algorithm. You guys have any idea?

Comment: Radix sort does not "often" (or ever) have complexity `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Sorting algorithms *based on pairwise comparing* have a theoretical lower bound on their time complexity of O(n log(n)).  Algorithms that are not based on pairwise comparing of the elements to be sorted can approach O(n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a simple one (known as ["counting sort"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) or "histogram sort", a degenerate case of ["bucket sort"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)):

1. Allocate an array with one slot for each non-negative integer less than `k`, and zero it. `O(k)`
2. Iterate over all elements of the input and count them in our array. `O(n)`
3. Iterate over our array and write the elements out in-order. `O(n+k)`

Thus, `O(n+k)`.

Comment: If step 2. is O(n), reading n elements and incrementing (read + write) the array of k elements n times, then wouldn't step 3 also be O(n), reading and decrementing the array of k elements n times and writing n elements?

Comment: @rcgldr: In step 2, we iterate over the input array (length n) once, and do the same simple operation for each. Thus, O(n). In step 3, we iterate over our side-array (length k), writing into our output-array exactly n times in the process, so O(iter+write) == O(k+n).

Answer (score 2):

Radix sort gives you O(n log k), not O(n log n) complexity. Since K is a fixed number independent of n, the resultant complexity is O(n * const), I.e. It is linear.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the kind of complexity. Average case O(n+k): [Bucket Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).

Radix sort should be O(m * n) though. (m being the length of the key used to sort)

Comment: If K is the maximum number (as opposed to the number of bits) then radix sort is `O(n log K)`, not `O(nK)`.

Answer (score 1):

create a new array of size K and just insert each element to the array in it own position..

lets say K=100

create an array of 100 integers - clear it.
and if you have the set {55, 2, 7, 34}.
you just need to the following:

```
array[55] = 1;
array[2] = 1;
array[7] = 1;
array[34] =1;
```

And the go over the array from start to end and just print the index of the cells that are == 1